# I am trying to check many values in php with array

Tags: php

What is wrong in the array condition? Even if corps is equal to any of these values it doesn't enter the `if` condition

```
while($row = $req->fetch()){

  $corps= $row->NVCDC;
  $list_ex = array("201","20","25","204");
  if(in_array($corps, $list_ex)){
    $daten = $row->DTN;
    $daterec = $row->DTR;
    if($daten < $daterec ){
      //do something
    }
```

Comment: Please clarify what the behavior currently is and what you expect or want it to be.

Comment: What is the output of: `var_dump($corps);`?

Comment: what I expect is when the variable $corps is equals 201 or 20 or 25 or 204 It must enter to the next bloq wich is:   $daten = $row->DTN;
    $daterec = $row->DTR;
    if($daten < $daterec ){
      //do something
    }

Comment: @Rizier123 it comes from a select query

Comment: @Davina Just tell us the output of that code, when you place it under the assignment^.

Comment: it just pass to "else"

Comment: Put it before the if statement. And you don't even have an else.

Comment: yes I have it but I just didn't put it here

Comment: What error do you get? For all I know it could be a database connection failure.

Comment: @Davina Now after you have put it there. What is the output?

Comment: My problem was with the getted varible from the base I wrote it wrong thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
//If $corps is a array u must do it this way
$corps = ["201","20"];
$list_ex = array("201","20","25","204");
foreach($corps as $corp)
{
    if(in_array($corp, $list_ex))
        echo "yes\n";
} //Will echo Yes 2 time

//If $corps is a string or number
$corps = "201";
$list_ex = array("201","20","25","204");
if(in_array($corps, $list_ex))
{
    echo "yes";
}//Will echo yes 1 time
?>
```

Double check the value of $corps , it maybe a array or the value is not what u think it is, if it a array then the same "**array**" must exist in the $list_ex

If $corps == [20,201] $list must have $list[[20,201]] for in_array to return TRUE

Comment: $corps is a variable getted from a database

Comment: var_dump($corps) check the type and value

Comment: it is a varchar and I'm sure that the value is one of the listed values in array